# Are there any efficient way to concatenate two json files in python

Tags: python, json

I have two json files of same  structure. The json entries are not nested and have strings as keys and integers as the corresponding values. I want to concatenate and save both the json files into a single json file. It is possible that some of them keys are present in both the files. In such case I need to add up the values, in my new json file.

I am aware that I can do the following

```
import json
#both values have integer as the values
a = json.loads(open('js1.json').read())
b = json.loads(open('js2.json').read())
c = a.copy()
for item in b.keys():
  try:
    c[item] += b[item]
  except:
    c[item] = b[item]

f = open('newjs.json','w')
json.dumps(c,f)
```

Here I am loading both json into separate dictionaries, and then writing the same to an anotehr dictionary. Are there any other efficient methods in terms of memory and speed to achieve the same?

Comment: For starters, `c = a.copy()` instead of your first loop. But why bother with a copy *at all* here since it doesn't matter what `a` looks like afterwards?

Comment: And how you merge two dictionaries depends entirely on their structure. Are there nested dictionaries or lists? What happens to string values for the same key, numbers, booleans?

Answer (score 4):

Just merge two dicts, thats it -

```
import json
a = json.loads(open('js1.json').read())
b = json.loads(open('js2.json').read())

def combine_dicts(*dicts):
    return reduce(lambda dict1, dict2: dict(zip(dict1.keys() + dict2.keys(), dict1.values() + dict2.values())), dicts)

c = combine_dicts(a, b)
```

Comment: In the op's code i think that {a:1,b:1} + {b:1,c:1} == {a:1,b:2,c:1}. Your solution won't work because dict(zip(...)) will keep only the last value of each common key.